# User details not showing on Angular website after signing in with MSAL.js

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

Hi I have an Angular website that is using ADB2C authentication with [Microsoft authentication library for Javascript](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular). The authentication is running well and I am able to log into the website. I want to display some of the login user details on the top navigation bar but after login I am not able to display these details (eg username, countries/instances in a select menu) even though the sign in process is running well. I can only display them after I refresh the page. After moving my code around I am not able to find why this is the problem. Below is the HTML template code and the component. Also a picture of the navigation bar (with the empty button and a select menu for the user details) upon signing in. I am trying to show the activeUser and the instances properties into the template.

[image]

```
<ul class="navbar-nav float-right">
    
    <li class="mr-2 d-flex align-items-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mx-1 btn-sm" *ngIf="loginDisplay">{{activeUser}}</button>
        
      <select class="form-control mx-1 form-control-sm" *ngIf="loginDisplay" [(ngModel)]="selectedInstance" (ngModelChange)='onInstanceChange($event)'>
        <option *ngFor="let instance of instances">{{ instance }}</option>
      </select>

        <button class="btn btn-light ml-1 btn-sm" *ngIf="!loginDisplay" (click)="login()">Login</button>
        <button class="btn btn-light ml-1 btn-sm" *ngIf="loginDisplay" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
@Component({
selector: "app-navigation",
templateUrl: "./navigation.component.html",
styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
@Output()
toggleSidebar = new EventEmitter<void>();

@Input()
user: any = { countryCode: "" };

public showSearch = false;

title = "RPT";
isIframe = false;
loginDisplay = false;
private readonly _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();

name='';
country='';

displayname='';
//user:any='';
currentuser: any="";
instances: string[] = [];
selectedinstance: string='';

activeUser: string | undefined="unknown user";
isAuthenticated=false;
idtoken: string='';

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  @Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration,
  private authService: MsalService,
  private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService,
  private tfapi: TfApi,
  private tfinstances: tfInstances
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  debugger;
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
    console.log(params);
  });

  this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener;
  this.setLoginDisplay();

  this.authService.instance.enableAccountStorageEvents(); // Optional - This will enable ACCOUNT_ADDED and ACCOUNT_REMOVED events emitted when a user logs in or out of another tab or window

  /**
   * You can subscribe to MSAL events as shown below. For more info,
   * visit: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/events.md
   */
  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
    .pipe(
      filter(
        (msg: EventMessage) =>
          msg.eventType === EventType.ACCOUNT_ADDED ||
          msg.eventType === EventType.ACCOUNT_REMOVED
      )
    )
    .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
      if (this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length === 0) {
        window.location.pathname = "/";
      } else {
        this.setLoginDisplay();
      }
    });

  this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
    .pipe(
      filter(
        (status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None
      ),
      takeUntil(this._destroying$)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.setLoginDisplay();
      this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      this.getTfinstances();
    });

  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
    .pipe(
      filter(
        (msg: EventMessage) =>
          msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS ||
          msg.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS ||
          msg.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS
      ),
      takeUntil(this._destroying$)
    )
    .subscribe(async (result: EventMessage) => {
      let payload = result.payload as AuthenticationResult;
      let idtokenClaims = payload.idTokenClaims as IdTokenClaimsWithPolicyId;
      this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);

      if (
        idtokenClaims.acr === b2cPolicies.names.signUpSignIn ||
        idtokenClaims.tfp === b2cPolicies.names.signUpSignIn
      ) {
        this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
      }

      this.idtoken=payload.idToken;

      /**
       * For the purpose of setting an active account for UI update, we want to consider only the auth response resulting
       * from SUSI flow. "acr" claim in the id token tells us the policy (NOTE: newer policies may use the "tfp" claim instead).
       * To learn more about B2C tokens, visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview
       */
      if (
        idtokenClaims.acr === b2cPolicies.names.editProfile ||
        idtokenClaims.tfp === b2cPolicies.names.editProfile
      ) {
        // retrieve the account from initial sing-in to the app
        const originalSignInAccount = this.authService.instance
          .getAllAccounts()
          .find(
            (account: AccountInfo) =>
              account.idTokenClaims?.oid === idtokenClaims.oid &&
              account.idTokenClaims?.sub === idtokenClaims.sub &&
              ((account.idTokenClaims as IdTokenClaimsWithPolicyId).acr ===
                b2cPolicies.names.signUpSignIn ||
                (account.idTokenClaims as IdTokenClaimsWithPolicyId).tfp ===
                  b2cPolicies.names.signUpSignIn)
          );

        let signUpSignInFlowRequest: SsoSilentRequest = {
          authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
          account: originalSignInAccount,
        };

        // silently login again with the signUpSignIn policy
        this.authService.ssoSilent(signUpSignInFlowRequest);
      }

      /**
       * Below we are checking if the user is returning from the reset password flow.
       * If so, we will ask the user to reauthenticate with their new password.
       * If you do not want this behavior and prefer your users to stay signed in instead,
       * you can replace the code below with the same pattern used for handling the return from
       * profile edit flow (see above ln. 74-92).
       */
      if (
        idtokenClaims.acr === b2cPolicies.names.resetPassword ||
        idtokenClaims.tfp === b2cPolicies.names.resetPassword
      ) {
        let signUpSignInFlowRequest: RedirectRequest | PopupRequest = {
          authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
          prompt: PromptValue.LOGIN, // force user to reauthenticate with their new password
          scopes: [],
        };

        this.login(signUpSignInFlowRequest);
      }

      return result;
    });

  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
    .pipe(
      filter(
        (msg: EventMessage) =>
          msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE ||
          msg.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_FAILURE
      ),
      takeUntil(this._destroying$)
    )
    .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
      // Checking for the forgot password error. Learn more about B2C error codes at
      // https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes
      if (result.error && result.error.message.indexOf("AADB2C90118") > -1) {
        let resetPasswordFlowRequest: RedirectRequest | PopupRequest = {
          authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.resetPassword.authority,
          scopes: [],
        };

        this.login(resetPasswordFlowRequest);
      }
    });
}

setLoginDisplay() {
  this.loginDisplay = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
}

checkAndSetActiveAccount() {
  /**
   * If no active account set but there are accounts signed in, sets first account to active account
   * To use active account set here, subscribe to inProgress$ first in your component
   * Note: Basic usage demonstrated. Your app may require more complicated account selection logic
   */
  let activeAccount = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();

  if (!activeAccount && this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
      let accounts = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts();
      // add your code for handling multiple accounts here
      this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
  }

  this.isAuthenticated= !!activeAccount;
  this.activeUser=activeAccount?.username;
}

async getTfinstances(){
const response=await this.tfapi.getUser(this.activeUser as string, this.idtoken);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('User not found or token expired, please sign in.');
          }
        this.user= await response.json();
        //this.displayname=this.user.DisplayName;
        //console.log(this.user);
        this.instances=this.tfinstances.listInstances(this.user.Visibility)
        console.log(this.instances);
}

login(userFlowRequest?: RedirectRequest | PopupRequest) {
  if (this.msalGuardConfig.interactionType === InteractionType.Popup) {
      if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
          this.authService.loginPopup({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest, ...userFlowRequest } as PopupRequest)
              .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
                  this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
              });
      } else {
          this.authService.loginPopup(userFlowRequest)
              .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
                  this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
              });
      }
  } else {
      if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
          this.authService.loginRedirect({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest, ...userFlowRequest } as RedirectRequest);
      } else {
          this.authService.loginRedirect(userFlowRequest);
      }
  }
}

logout() {
  const activeAccount =
    this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount() ||
    this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0];

  if (this.msalGuardConfig.interactionType === InteractionType.Popup) {
    this.authService.logoutPopup({
      account: activeAccount,
    });
  } else {
    this.authService.logoutRedirect({
      account: activeAccount,
    });
  }
}

editProfile() {
  let editProfileFlowRequest: RedirectRequest | PopupRequest = {
      authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.editProfile.authority,
      scopes: [],
  };

  this.login(editProfileFlowRequest);
}

// unsubscribe to events when component is destroyed
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this._destroying$.next(undefined);
  this._destroying$.complete();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cloned Angular B2C sample in my environment from this [GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular-b2c-sample-app) link and got below results:

When I ran the above sample by modifying values like **clientID** and **authority** in environment.dev.ts file, I got login screen like below:

[image]

When user clicks on `Login` button, it redirect to sign in like below:

[image]

Once sign in is successful, id claims of **signed-in user** are displayed like this:

[image]

To get these details in select menu, I made few changes in code like below:

**app.component.ts:**

```
getClaims(claims: Record<string, any>) {
        if (claims) {
          Object.entries(claims).forEach((claim: [string, unknown], index: number) => {
            console.log(claims);
            this.dataSource.push({id: index, claim: claim[0], value: claim[1]});
            if (this.dataSource[11]){
                this.isgivenname=true;
                console.log(this.dataSource[11]);
            } 
            if (this.dataSource[9]){
                this.iscountry=true;
                console.log(this.dataSource[9]);
            }            
          });
        }
      }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
    <div ngbDropdown>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" id="gfg"
          ngbDropdownToggle>Select</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu="gfg">
      <button ngbDropdownItem *ngIf="isgivenname">Name: {{dataSource[10].value}}</button>
      <button ngbDropdownItem *ngIf="iscountry">Country: {{dataSource[9].value}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

After saving the above changes, I got `Name` and `Country` in **select** menu successfully without refreshing the browser like this:

[image]

You can find my complete code in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/SrideviM-5/sri.git).